# Sign issue deriving SHM of Electric dipole in external uniform electric field

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, harmonic-oscillator, dipole-moment

If we have an electric dipole as shown:

[image]

Net torque on system = $Fdsin\theta$= Rate of change of angular momentum = $I \ddot \theta $

For small displacements along line of E field, $sin\theta \approx \theta$

So $Fd\theta=I\ddot \theta$.

I want to show this is SHM, where have I dropped my negative sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As drawn you have taken $\theta$ to be positive in the anticlockwise direction?

The torque is in the clockwise (negative) direction so should be written as $-Fd \,\theta$.